# std::string - изменение размера

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста:

```
std::string my_string = "Hello world";

my_string .resize(1);

std::cout<<my_string.capacity()<<std::endl;
```

При изменении размера контейнера через resize() - в меньшую сторону сама емкость выделенной памяти не меняется(в vs2019) - это по стандарту или же стандарт этого строго не описывает и это на усмотрение компилятора - может изменить, а может не менять ?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, `resize` никогда не изменяет `capacity`, т.к. это может привести к инвалидации итераторов, в случае перераспределения памяти. По-крайней мере в [документации к вектору](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize), это указано. Думаю, то же самое относится и к строке.

Comment: Изменение емкости в меньшую сторону может производить только метод `shrink_to_fit`.

Comment: №1. Не компилятор выполняет реализацию , следовательно не компилятор решает когда перераспределять память.  Компилятор  только "читает"  существующую реализацию, так что, по любому,  это не на усмотрение компилятора, а на усмотрение тех, кто пишет реализацию для данного компилятора.  №2.  Ни одна реализация не будет перераспределять память при попытке уменьшить объем в меньшую сторону, потому что это  (если сказать коротко) будет глупой затеей, а стандартные реализации  должны быть,(как минимум)  грамотными и обдуманными.

Answer (score 0):

Простой пример для наглядности:

```
 my_string.resize(foo());
```

Мы не знаем значение. возвращаемое  функцией `foo`, но в случае, если она вернет значение больше уже занимаемого объема, то нужно  увеличить объем, в обратном случаи нам не нужно уменьшить  этот объем, потому мы не вызываем `shrink_to_fit`. Стандартная реализация не будет  этого делать,   не зная наши намерения, лишний раз увеличивая расходы  и риск запутывать код. Нам только предоставляются добротные инструменты  с учетом безопасности исключений, и мы решаем как ими пользоваться.  Компилятор не имеет компетенцию  изменить реализацию.